# How to access the window object after a window.location.reload?

Tags: javascript

Say I want to continuously refresh a web page every 15 seconds.

And then I want to read some HTML element on the page.

Is there someway to do this in a pure client side javascript way?

If i do:

```
document.getElementsById();
// some logic that i am interested in.
window.location.reload()
// is there someway to access the reloaded window?
```

Is there someway I can access the window object that will come?

Comment: Do you mean read the HTML of the reloaded page or of the current page?

Comment: @Xufox The reloaded page.

Comment: Then you probably should do an AJAX request and parse the response as HTML.

Comment: @Xufox What if the HTML is rendered on Client side? For example a react app. I had to wait for the HTML to be generated.

Comment: Then, alternatively, you could put the code “after the reload” in an `onload` listener on the page.

Comment: @Xufox Actually. I think I can build a very dumb webpage with an iframe pointing to the website I am interested in. And then i can refresh it however I want. But this will not work well for websites with proper security header.

Comment: @guest271314 I need to access the returned html. But getting the window object will also work.

Comment: @Xufox AFAIK. window.onload = function() {//something} window.location.reload() will basically lose the onload.

Comment: But you’re only reloading the page after 15 seconds right? The `onload` will fire immediately — right after the reload.

Comment: "// is there someway to access the reloaded window?" No, because the document containing this comment doesn't exist anymore. I.e. nothing will be executed in the current document after `window.location.reload()`, except `(before)unload` events, but they are not aware of the becoming document.